# Populating a list on activex control given a checkbox condition

Tags: list, vba, excel

I would imagine the solution to this is something very simple and straight forward. I am creating an Excel sheet with activex controls. Using VBA, I am trying to populate a listbox (given a range of cells) once a checkbox is checked.

The following is the code that I am using but I am getting an error:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
Me.List_GR.RowSource = "C32:C34"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will populate the listbox when the checkbox is checked, it will not change the listbox when you uncheck it unless you add additional code.

```
  Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
        If CheckBox1 = True Then
            ListBox1.List = Range("A1:A6").Value
        End If
    End Sub
```

Make sure you have the rowsource blank in the properties box of the listbox